# How do I use :Tabular only for delimiters after a certain pattern?

Tags: regular-expression, plugin-tabular

How can I use the Tabular plugin to align by ";" after "//"?

With text:

```
Line 1 ; B // Comment 1 ; Comment 2
Line 2 C // Comment 3    ; Comment 4
```

After running `:Tabularize /;` I get:

```
Line 1                ; B // Comment 1 ; Comment 2
Line 2 C // Comment 3 ; Comment 4
```

But how do I tabularize so that I get

```
Line 1  ; B // Comment 1 ; Comment 2
Line 2 C   // Comment 3  ; Comment 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
:Tabularize ///[^;]*\zs;
```

To break it down:

- `//` – match literal `//`.
- `[^;]*` – match zero or more characters except `;`.
- `\zs` – set the start of the match. This is the "magic" in the regexp that makes it work; without it, the match would start at the first character (`/` in this case) and Tabular would align on that, but with this it will match at the character after `\zs` (the desired `;`).
  These sort of advanced regular expression operators can be rather hard to grok, so don't worry if you didn't quite follow that. I would encourage you to experiment. Also see [`:help /\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fzs).
- `;` – match literal `;`.